# Access violation writing location 0xXXXXXXXX

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am writing a c++ program implementing the Merge Sort iteratively. The main code is shown below and I cannot understand why I am having the "Access violation writing location 0xXXXXXXXX" error, even though I allocated much more memory (1 gb) in the same way in another program.

```
void main()
{
    //int a[size];
    int* a =  new int(size); //initialising an int array dynamically contains 16777216 el
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i]= 1 + rand() % 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0;  (size / 2) / pow((double)2, i)>= 1; i++)
    {
        int n = pow((double)2, i);
        int offset = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < (size / 2) / pow((double)2, i); j++)
        {
            int* tmp = new int(n);
            merge(a + offset, n, a + offset + n, n, tmp);
            memcpy(a + offset, tmp, n*2 * sizeof(int));
            offset += pow((double)2, i+1);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        //printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Use `new int [size]`, not `new int (size)`. The latter creates one and initiializes it to `size`. Also, http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: `void main()`? What book are you using?

Comment: It now gives me the error "Windows has triggered a breakpoint in merge_sort_ash_seq.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in merge_sort_ash_seq.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while merge_sort_ash_seq.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You allocate only memory enough for 1 integer: `new int(size)` and assign it as `size`. So you don't have 1GB of memory pointed by a. Accessing it beyond 1 integer is undefined behavior, which can give you an access violation.

Change `new int(size)` to square brackets: `new int[size]`.

And better still, use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Yes. I like vectors too and use it everyday

Answer (score 2):

A slight typo in the allocation code. This line

```
int* a =  new int(size);
```

creates a single `int` with the *value* of `size`.

Try this instead

```
int* a =  new int[size];
```