# Heap corruption with large memory allocation sizes C++

Tags: c++

This code causes a heap corruption corresponding to Visual Studio 2010.
What causes heap corruption? What part of this code is causing it?

```
#define size 65536
int main()
{
    int* a =  new int[size];//size is equal to
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i]= 1 + rand() % 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0;  (size / 2) / pow((double)2, i)>= 1; i++)
    {
        int n = pow((double)2, i);
        int offset = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < (size / 2) / pow((double)2, i); j++)
        {
            int* tmp = new int[n];
            merge(a + offset, n, a + offset + n, n, tmp);
            memcpy(a + offset, tmp, n*2 * sizeof(int));
            offset += pow((double)2, i+1);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you have a memory-leak; you are never freeing the memory pointed to by `tmp`.

Comment: void merge(int* a, int a_size, int* b, int b_size, int* c)
{
 for(int a_i = 0, b_i = 0, c_i = 0; c_i < a_size + b_size; c_i++)
 {
  if(a_i == a_size)
  {
   while(b_i < b_size)
   {
    c[c_i] = b[b_i];
    b_i++;
    c_i++;
   }
  }
  else if(b_i == b_size)
  {
   while(a_i < a_size)
   {
    c[c_i] = a[a_i];
    a_i++;
    c_i++;
   }
  }
  else if(a[a_i] < b[b_i])
  {
   c[c_i] = a[a_i];
   a_i++;
  }
  else
  {
   c[c_i] = b[b_i];
   b_i++;
  }
 }
}

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `offset`, etc. *never* take you outside the bounds of your array?

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: You are doing truly wacky and inappropriate things with pow() here, IMO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access violation writing location 0xXXXXXXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373427/access-violation-writing-location-0xxxxxxxxx)

Comment: it takes to much effort to edit the damn question Oli Charlesworth

Comment: @Nashwan: -1. It takes almost no effort at all.  If your expect people to help you, then don't be lazy...

Answer (score 3):

Suspect the memcpy is the problem. You're copying (n * 2 * sizeof(int)) bytes from tmp, while you only allocated n * sizeof(int) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Heap corruption simply means that you have allocated a blcok of memory and then written data outside that block. Typically this means you've written past the end of the array.

A small amount of overwriting will hit "guard words" that are placed after your memory allocation, so the runtime will detect anbd report heap corruption while your program continues to run ok. However, if you write further, you may corrupt some other piece of critical data (causing undefined results when your program tries to use the data) or running off the end of your memory map and giving a fatal access violation error.

Check that the indexes into your arrays are always in the range 0..Length-1

If you can't calculate what the maximum index used will be, then put a line of code in to check that the index is within this range, and break into the debugger if it's not. i.e. check that the values you are passing into merge/memcpy are always within range. (Chances are that they write one element too many - a quick bodge for this is to allocate a bit more memory than you "need", but it's obviously not the correct solution - you need to be sure that you only write the data you intend to)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated enough space for `tmp`:

```
int* tmp = new int[2*n];
```

The incrementing in the merge code `for (..; ...; c_i++`) looks very suspicious too.

You probably have a couple of bugs, use a debugger or write trace messages and check what's going on - verify that you don't write out of bounds.

Comment: No I didn't... Thank you